# Safari: React-bootstrap dropdown component on esc key press dropdown menu not working i.e., not hiding

Tags: dropdown, react-bootstrap, esc-key

In Safari browser, React-bootstrap dropdown menu component not hiding on esc key press, Please help on how to hide the menu.

```
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Dropdown>
      <Dropdown.Toggle variant="success" id="dropdown-basic">
        Dropdown Button
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-1">Action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-2">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#/action-3">Something else</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}

export default BasicExample;
```